# solr on nginx - solr admin page

Tags: nginx, solr

I am trying to run solr behind the nginx proxy, and my nginx config looks like so (most of the code from [here](https://github.com/o19s/solr_nginx/blob/master/solr.conf)):

```
upstream my_solr_server {
      server 127.0.0.1:8983;
 }


server {

    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;


    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
    server_name search.mysite.com;

    client_max_body_size 10G;
    large_client_header_buffers 32 128k;



    # Some Default NGINX installs have "Welcome to NGINX" at the / location
    # This disables that
    location / {
        return 404;
    }

    # Create a location block for each handler you'd like to whitelist
    location /solr/mycollection/select {

        # Only allow GET requests
            limit_except GET {
                    deny all;
            }





        # prevents 502 bad gateway error
        proxy_buffers 32 128k;
        proxy_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 400;
        proxy_connect_timeout 400;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://my_solr_server;
            break;
        }

}
```

}

Now, when I do for example:
http://search.mysite.com/solr/mycollection/select?q=search+something&wt=json&indent=true&fl=id&rows=1000

.. it works fine. However, when I try (to look at the admin page):
http://search.mysite.com/solr/

I keep getting 404's... - even when I comment out the `location /` directive
I am not really sure why this is happening here.

Any advice on how to solve this issue would be really helpful!

Comment: `# This disables that` — OMG

Comment: You con't have anything that will match `/solr/`, except `location /` that returns you 404 as you desire.